# Test availability of a web page

Tags: script, automation, website

We have a page that proposes some administrative appointements that are almost impossible to have, because of the irregular and unconstant updates from the site administrators.
Once these administrators updates the new schedule times, there is need to quickly be present online to take the available appointments. (The page is like [this one](http://www.seine-saint-denis.gouv.fr/booking/create/1194).)

To check if there are available appointments, there is need to open the page, check a checkbox (or radio button) and press a submit button.

Then, depending if a update in schedule was made or not by the admins, you have the available appointments table. If any update the page says "***Any appointment not yet available. Try again later!***"

So is there a way to atomate this behavior to periodically check the page and, say, send me an email if there are available appointments?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this can be automated. Look into automated website testing tools, like Selenium.

Comment: why a downvote?

Comment: On superuser there are some community members that downvote quite liberally. Here, have an upvote.

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded Selenium for C#... I know a little bit that language... but I don't really understand what to use from that project for my concrete task. Do you ha ve a suggestion on that?

Comment: You could do this w/ a Perl script, and curl with POST data. My https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-renew-cl.pl does something like this (auto-renews Craigslist postings)

Comment: @serhio To start, use the part with the GUI. Let it record your actions to create a "test case". Your test case, which you can run by pressing a button, is "open the page, check a checkbox (or radio button) and press a submit button." If you get that working, your next step is to automatically convert the test to C# and go from there.